# Sorting mysql_fetch_row or mysql_fetch_assoc in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I've a mysql_fetch_row array in PHP and I want to sort it based on one of its column values. I've absolutely no idea how to do it. Help please! Thank you.

I have something like this:

```
$doctors = array();

    if ($numrows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $doc_lat = $row[9];
            $doc_lng = $row[10];

            $dist =  distance($user_lat, $user_lng, $doc_lat, $doc_lng, "K");
            $dist = round($dist, 1);

            if ($dist < 15) {
                $row[19] = $dist;
                $doctors[] = $row;
            }

        }
    }
```

In above code, I've doctor[] which is an array of mysql_fetch_row and I want to sort it on the basis of 19th value ($dist) that I added to the $row.

Comment: Why not just store the arrays in PHP and then apply whatever sorting algorithm you want on the element in each array?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$doctors['compare'] = $row;

$arr_common_all_new=sortArrayByColumValues($doctors, 'compare', DESC_NUM, $sticky_fields ) ;

function sortArrayByColumValues($arr, $field, $sort_type, $sticky_fields = array() ) {
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $is_contiguous = true;
    if(!empty($grouped_arr)) {
        $last_value = end($grouped_arr[$i]);

        if(!($sticky_fields == array())) {
            foreach ($sticky_fields as $sticky_field) {
                if ($value[$sticky_field] <> $last_value[$sticky_field]) {
                    $is_contiguous = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($is_contiguous)
        $grouped_arr[$i][] = $value;
    else
        $grouped_arr[++$i][] = $value;
}
$code = '';
switch($sort_type) {
    case ASC_AZ:
        $code .= 'return strcasecmp($a["'.$field.'"], $b["'.$field.'"]);';
        break;
    case DESC_AZ:
        $code .= 'return (-1*strcasecmp($a["'.$field.'"], $b["'.$field.'"]));';
        break;
    case ASC_NUM:
        $code .= 'return ($a["'.$field.'"] - $b["'.$field.'"]);';
        break;
    case DESC_NUM:
        $code .= 'return ($b["'.$field.'"] - $a["'.$field.'"]);';
        break;
}
 $compare = create_function('$a, $b', $code);

foreach($grouped_arr as $grouped_arr_key=>$grouped_arr_value)
    usort ( $grouped_arr[$grouped_arr_key], $compare );

$arr = array();
foreach($grouped_arr as $grouped_arr_key=>$grouped_arr_value)
    foreach($grouped_arr[$grouped_arr_key] as $grouped_arr_arr_key=>$grouped_arr_arr_value)
        $arr[] = $grouped_arr[$grouped_arr_key][$grouped_arr_arr_key];

return $arr;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort` function to sort an array using a user-defined comparing option:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ((int)$a[0] == (int)$b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((int)$a[0] < (int)$b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = mysql_fetch_row($result);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

for an array. Or

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ((int)$a["Id"] == (int)$b["Id"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((int)$a["Id"] < (int)$b["Id"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

for associative array.

Comment: You can just subtract *b* from *a*: `function cmp($a, $b) { return $b[0] - $a[0]; }`

Answer (score 1):

> **Use this query**

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `id` ASC");

//Output query results
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['username'] . '<br />';
}

In php use this code
```

> You can use usort() comparison function.

```
$order = array(19);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['id'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['id'], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

Reference [Php usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

> Note:use **MySQLI** to avoid hijacking...

Comment: Use `usort` function to arrange the array according to way.